# Wamp can not see php mongodb extension

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I have a Wamp with a few PHP versions installed on it. The current one is 7.4.9. I needed to install MongoDB extension on it so according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php), I added the mongodb.dll file to the ext directory and then add extension=php_mongodb.dll to the php.ini file. There are two ini files. One is in `bin/php/php7.4.9` directory and second is in `bin/apache2/bin` directory. Both of them contain the required line extension=php_mongodb.dll. But if I try to show active extensions it shows me the error:

> The 'php_mongodb.dll' extension file exists but there is no
> 'extension=php_mongodb.dll' line in php.ini.

As I said above both ini files contain the required line and all services have been restarted. What should I do now? I don't see any other php.ini files. Thanks for any help.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

Comment: Did you remember to restart apache after editing the ini files?

Comment: I did it. also I did restart of whole PC. But it seems it works after second restart of PC. Does not make sense....